.NET Framework errors get resolved after restarting Visual Studio
I was working with a .NET Framework solution when I got errors that stated that some assemblies were missing even though I had the NuGet libraries installed.
The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'
The type or namespace name 'ILogger<>' could not be found
... and many more like these.
I tried restoring nugets, but it didn't seem to work. I reopened Visual Studio and it all got fixed. That got me wondering what had happened by restarting VS? And in case this happens again, what should be my go-to resolution strategy?

From experience restarting VS is the first thing I do when there are errors or issues that don't make sense. I think that sometimes VS gets a little out of sync with the code or something got cached that is no longer correct. Restarting VS starts everything from scratch. How many times does turning it off and on again fix things, it takes very little time so should probably be one of the first things to try.

I've experienced this only with .net framework solutions and never encountered any problems with .net core. Have you noticed any such thing?

Can't say that I've noticed it specifically happening with just .NET Framework.

As phuzi mentioned in the comments, VS maintains a cache containing information about projects and their dependencies. Sometimes, this cache may get corrupted or out-of-sync. In my case, I did a git pull on a fairly active branch for a big application after several months that could have gotten the cache to go out-of-sync I suppose.
Here's another question without an accepted answer, but it proves that this problem is so common. I would also just restart VS and try a build.
